# round of the sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

How to convert sql.Timestamp in the formate MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.S to sql.timestamp with the formate MM/dd/yyyy 00.00.00.0

Basically i am trying to round of the timstamp just to take the date

Comment: What database are you using? It might be a better idea to use the database internal conversion function. Like `TO_TIMESTAMP` in Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on local timezone, you need Calendar

```
    Timestamp t = ...
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(t.getTime());
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    t = new Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
```